# One web service multiple sites

Tags: c#, web-services

I don't know whether this is even possible or I imagine (according to my habit of over thinking) will bring through numerous issues but let me give it a go.

I have an idea where I would like a single web service which a user will send a request to, for example logging in. The response back dictates a URL where they get redirected too so essentially this means for me less maintenance in updating web services etc as its all in one place.

What I am trying to do is have a single service that routes people to the correct server to get data from instead of having the end user to have knowledge of the endpoint address etc.

For example, I have a system on the web and want it visible to my windows, android and apple devices but there is a specific site for each client. Ideally, I only want the user to enter their login credentials and the web service does the rest, i.e. fetches data from the correct data source.

I imagine this is common practice for many systems but I guess is there a risk factor in that a user being sent data from another request if they happen at the same time? Obviously this is a huge flaw and perhaps I am going completely the wrong route here.

I would appreciate any resources to links, books etc. I was unsure of what to search for on the web so thought this is the best place for such questions.

This is a system I am developing to help me understand web services better in general. A little project I am working on to help me explore different techniques and approaches towards development :)

Comment: You know how to issue a redirect, right?  Just have your code dynamically figure out what redirect to issue based on the user/browser/etc, and issue that redirect.  Your worry about one user getting another user's data is the same as one user getting another user's web page - that essentially impossible with any sane webserver so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a service oriented architecture, but your requirements are a bit vague. Is it possible to create a centralized authentication service for multiple applications that returns redirect URLs? Of course.Your concern about one request receiving the data of another person's (or application's) request is unlikely to become an issue. Your web server will make sure the correct response stays tied to the correct request.

Comment: Oh right I thought what I was thinking wasn't possible and thank you for clearing that issue which isn't an issue. I shall look into Service Oriented Architectures heard the term before but never paid attention to it. Thank you.